# How To attach an Event Reciever to a Specific List in SP2007

Tags: event-handlers, event-receivers

I'm having trouble binding my event receiver (ItemAdding) event to a specific list.  I created a Feature Receiver and tried both the GUID and Name.  But, I have another list that uses the same column name that I am trapping for as the list I want to bind to, so it seems the event trips in this other list as well.  I thought the Feature Receiver would prevent this.  Here is how Im attempting this:

```
Public Overrides Sub FeatureActivated(ByVal properties As SPFeatureReceiverProperties)
    Try
        'Get a Reference to the Current Web
        Dim oWeb As SPWeb = properties.Feature.Parent

        'Get a Reference to the PEEIT%20StateLicenses List (Using the Lists Guid)
        Dim oGUID As New Guid("{26712059-15E5-48A6-A26D-8A9A521418CF}")
        'Dim oList As SPList = oWeb.Lists(oGUID)
        Dim oList As SPList = oWeb.Lists("PEEIT State Licenses")
        Dim sAssembyName As String = "WEC.SPS.Feature.SR558,Version=1.0.0.0,culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c6f26b52f1522b5"
        Dim sReceiverName As String = "WEC.SPS.Feature.SR558.EnforcePEEITListIntegrity"

        'Attach Event Receiver to Specific List (PEEIT%20StateLicenses List)
        oList.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdding, sAssembyName, sReceiverName)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        'Throw a message in the ULS Logging
        Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.PortalLog.LogString("Exception Occurred on SR558-FeatureActivated: {0} || {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
```

Bismarck

Comment: I had the exact same question... I need to develop an event receiver for a specific document library, and for no other list/library anywhere else in the SP portal. Did any of the answers below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

To do that you have just an only way: you must check the name of the list.
You can check this name in two ways:
1 - Check the name by code (you can read the list name or list title):

```
properties.ListItem.Name
properties.ListItem.Title
```

2 - In the file Elements.xml change the following line:

```
<Receivers ListTemplateId="xxx">
```

Where xxx is a number with the following:

```
<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/TestAnnouncements">
```

Answer (score 0):

There's known tool that can do it - http://sharepointforum.com/Documents/Useful%20Files/EventHandlerExplorer.zip. It's a project in Visual Studio so you can not only use this tool to attach your receiver to single list instance but see how to do it in code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change in "Receivers" tag in "Elements.xml "
as
"Receivers ListTemplateId="someNumber" to 
"Receivers ListUrl="Lists/yourListName".